# Subprocess.check_output enters hung state

Tags: python-3.x, ansible-2.x

Although the yaml is executed and execution is finised , still python code don't terminate.

```
subprocess.check_output("nohup ansible-playbook ansible_final.yml -u ec2-user &",shell=True)
```

Comment: using `nohup` and background with `check_output` is looking for trouble

Comment: I am just trying to put it in background

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
with open('error.err','w') as ferr, open('output.out','w') as fout:
                p=subprocess.Popen('ansible-playbook ansible_final.yml -u ec2-user &', stdout=fout, stderr=ferr,preexec_fn=os.setsid,shell=True)
```